# Forking in loops

Tags: c, loops, fork

Say I have a process. I fork it, then it has a parent and a child.
I want the parent to write from 2 to n to a pipe and the child to read from it.

The child will pass through each value through some conditions, and they don't pass any of the conditions, it will go back to the parent by calling exit().

In the parent, I will need to fork the original process and now the current parent will read 3 into the fd used in the master process and write to the newly created child, which goes through what the previous child went through.

```
if (pid > 0){ //parent which writes n to fd
    close(fd[0]); //close read
    for (j = 2; j <= n; j++){
        if (write(fd[1], &j, sizeof(int)) == -1){ //write j = 2 to fd
            perror("write j");
        }
    }
    close(fd[1]); //close write

    int status;

    if(wait(&status) != -1){
        if (WIFEXITED(status)){
            if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 2){
                pid = fork() //should I even be calling fork here?
        }
    }
}

else{ //CHILD        
    close(fd[1]); //close write
    for (j = 2; j <= n; j++){
        if (read(fd[0], &j, sizeof(int)) == -1){ //read j from fd
            perror("read j");
        }
    if (SOME CONDITION){
        exit(2);
    }
```

So far this only gets me through value 2, and I'm not sure make the parent send the value 3 into the next child.

Here's a diagram if my explanation was confusing.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to leave the child end of the pipe open in the parent process, and pass that to the next child that is created.  Sorry, haven't used linux in a while, and I don't have a linux box right now, but I figured since this is kind of psuedocode at this point, it wouldn't hurt too much to try.  If you want to be able to hand an arbitrary n, you'll have to either loop or use recursion, with loop being preferably because it won't use stack memory for each iteration.

Also not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do, so I made a few guesses. So, something like:

```
int keep_going = 1;
while(keep_going){
     pid = fork(); 
     if (pid > 0){ //parent which writes n to fd

/* can't close read, have to pass it to next child
          close(fd[0]);*/  //close read
          for (j = 2; j <= n; j++){
               if (write(fd[1], &j, sizeof(int)) == -1){ //write j = 2 to fd
                    perror("write j");
               }
          }
/* can't close write either, since it gets closed in child, so that
          would have to be rewritten to check if it is open before
          closing.  close(fd[1]);*/ //close write

          int status;

          if(wait(&status) != -1){
               if (WIFEXITED(status)){
                    if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 2){
                         continue;  /* continues the while loop */
                    } 
                    /* handle errors */
                    break;
               }
               /* handle errors */
               break;
          }
          /* handle more errors */
          break;
          assert(0); /* shouldn't be here */
     }

     else{ //CHILD
          close(fd[1]); //close write
          for(;;) {  /* child needs its own loop */
               for (j = 2; j <= n; j++){
                    if (read(fd[0], &j, sizeof(int)) == -1){ //read j from fd
                         perror("read j");
                    }
                    if (SOME CONDITION){
                         exit(2);
                    }
                    /* going to repeat for(;;) loop for next n */
               }
           }
     }
     assert(0); /* shouldn't be here */
}
```

Comment: I pretty much understand where you're getting, but I'm not too sure on why would child need its own loop.

Comment: @user3291818 Does the child go through more than one integer?  I wasn't sure about that actually, but the point is that the child has to stay in that else clause, otherwise there will be a fork in the child process as the loop iterates.